# How can I run the .bat file and generate the .js file

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

I have the question like the title above. So for example:
How can I run the Combined.bat file and next generate the Combined.js file?
Any tools do that?

Thanks for answers :)

Comment: what's inside `combine.js` file? how do you want to run it? manually clicking on the .bat file?

Comment: We need a bit more detail than that to help!

Comment: When I clicked on the .bat file a moment before the .bat file does nothing, but when I run now after install npm this .bat file run clearly. Thanks for yours answers :)